# I need help getting autoplay to work via [getElementById]

Tags: javascript, html

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/m656xw8s/24/

I've been trying to get autoplay to work, can someone show me what the correct code would be? Using the code I provided. Using [**getElementById**]

```
var player = document.getElementById('player').autoplay; document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = true;
```

---

```
<button id="playButton" style="border:none; width: 200px; height: 200px; cursor: pointer; font-family:Tahoma; font-weight: bold;font-size:14px; background-color:red;color:blue;" onclick="  
var player = document.getElementById('player').autoplay;
document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = true;
var player = document.getElementById('player').volume='1.0';
var button = document.getElementById('playButton');
  var player = document.getElementById('player');
  if (player.paused) {
    playButton.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    player.play();
  } else { 
    playButton.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    player.pause();
  }">
  </button>

<audio id="player" style="display:none;">
  <source src='http://hi5.1980s.fm/;' type='audio/mpeg' />
</audio>
```

Comment: on your audio tag add autoplay attribute, see the my answer below for a working demo :). Also added a code on how to set it via getElementByID

Comment: I updated the working demo below and done some code clean up on your code. Please check the updated answer below

Comment: Looks like you are not showing all your code, exactly what do you mean by "how do I add `.volume='1.0'` onto the 2nd one?". More importantly why did you add all that JavaScript in an attribute! There is a better way to do that.

Comment: ok. thank you for putting it back. I was trying to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the autoplay then load.

> http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_prop_autoplay

**Update:**

```js
        document.getElementById('playButton').addEventListener('click', autoPlayToggle);
        document.getElementById('autovolume_range').addEventListener('change', changeVol);
        //Only getElementById once!
        var player = document.getElementById("player");
        var autoplaytext = document.getElementById("autoplay_text");
        var autovolumetext = document.getElementById("autovolume_range");
        //Boolean from localstorage to keep state of the player
        var autoPlayOn = autoplaytext.value = (localStorage.getItem("keepAutoPlay") === "true");
        var setVolumeOn = autovolumetext.value = parseFloat(localStorage.getItem("keepVolume"));
        
        player.volume = setVolumeOn;
        player.autoplay = autoPlayOn;
        player.load();
        
        //Force play if it dosen't autoplay after refresh
        if (player.autoplay == true) {
          player.play();
        } else {
          player.pause();
        }
        
        //Function
        //When the user refreshes the page it will keep the autoplay state
        function autoPlayToggle() {
          if (player.paused) {
            player.play();
            player.autoplay = true;
          } else {
            player.pause();
            player.autoplay = false;
          }
          //Show the state in a text box
          autoplaytext.value = player.autoplay;
          //Save updated state to your local disk
          localStorage.setItem("keepAutoPlay", autoplaytext.value);
        }
        
        //Save state of volume
        function changeVol() {
         player.volume = this.value;
          localStorage.setItem("keepVolume", this.value);
        }
```

```html
    <button id="playButton" style="border:none; width: 200px; height: 200px; cursor: pointer; font-family:Tahoma; font-weight: bold;font-size:14px; background-color:red;color:blue;">
      </button>
    <audio id="player" style="display:none;" >
      <source src='http://hi5.1980s.fm/;' type='audio/mpeg'/>
    </audio>
    AutoPlay: <input id="autoplay_text" />
    AutoVolume: <input type="range" step="0.1" min="0.0" max="1.0" id="autovolume_range" />
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/LeroyRon/dtnrdjd5/

Comment: I'm trying to add this [.volume='1.0';] Onto this [var player = document.getElementById('player'); if (player.paused) {

Comment: what you are entering is a string player.volume='1.0'... with single quotes won't work. Do it like player.volume = 1.0; 
10% = (0.1)
50% = (0.5)
100% = (1.0)

Comment: How come I have it set to '0.0' single quotes I press play and no audio is coming out? https://jsfiddle.net/m656xw8s/35/ How come you said it doesn't work using single quotes? Can you please explain in your response to what you were referring to?

Comment: guess I was being to literal, you could use quotes to set volume, but it's not a good practice at my level because quotes are used for strings not numbers in general programming.

Comment: Can you show me on jsfiddle how I would do it using your method? https://jsfiddle.net/m656xw8s/35/

Comment: These don't get quotes either? .style.backgroundColor = 'red';

Comment: red is a word and words are strings use double (") or single (') quotes yes

Comment: I found this, and there's no quotes around the volume numbers, so you're probably right. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_prop_volume.asp Thanks.

Comment: enter code like the one above inbetween tags and below the buttons and text
<buttons> and <html> 
<script>
code... (like the one above)
</script>

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add attribute auto play to your audio tag see the updated code below; Based on your code you are redeclaring player multiple times see the updated code below. Your auto play is triggered on button click based on your code, you may want to separate the javascript codes to the button and just trigger a method indicated on your button click event.

You will need to use removeAttribute to remove the autoplay from your audio element. I added the code on how to do it below.

```js
//player declared outside of the audioPlay method to make it accessible inside the audioPlay method
 var player = document.getElementById('player');

 //auto play set outside playAudio method outside of the button click event method
 player.setAttribute('autoplay', '');
//to set autoplay false uncomment the code below
 //player.removeAttribute('autoplay'); 

//playAudio is triggered on button click event
function playAudio(){
  player.setAttribute('volume', 1.0);

  var button = document.getElementById('playButton');

 if (player.paused) {
    playButton.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    player.play();
  } else {
    playButton.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    player.pause();
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="playButton" style="border:none; width: 200px; height: 200px; cursor: pointer; font-family:Tahoma; font-weight: bold;font-size:14px; background-color:red;color:blue;" onclick="  
playAudio()">
  </button>


<audio id="player" style="display:none;">
  <source src='http://hi5.1980s.fm/;' type='audio/mpeg' />
</audio>
```

Comment: When I set it to false, it still plays. so it's not working. var player = document.getElementById('player').autoplay;
document.getElementById('player').innerHTML = false; https://jsfiddle.net/a0nq71mb/2/

Comment: you are using the code inside a button click event, that's is why it wont trigger automatically plus you are redeclaring player variable multiple times, I added explanation of the issue I will update my answer to provide you a working demo

Comment: autoplay is executed when the attribute autoplay is present on the audio tag, you need to use removeAttribute to remove autoplay :) It is provided on the code

Comment: Instead of having two of these, can I put volume with the 2nd one? and how would I do this?

1.) var player = document.getElementById('player').volume='1.0';
2.) var player = document.getElementById('player');
  if (player.paused) {

Comment: You mean you want to remove autoplay on pause? If so then that's possible, although I can't get the sense of it since the audio will be on paused status

Comment: Instead of having 2 of these, how do I add .volume='1.0'; onto the 2nd one?

1s.) var player = document.getElementById('player').volume='1.0'; 

2.) var player = document.getElementById('player'); if (player.paused) {

Comment: Please update your question to better illustrate what you really wan't to do. Your question has been answered with the code provided above. This is to make sure that other users having your issue is provided with the correct answer and answer only specific to the question being posted.

Comment: The question is now entirely different from the previous one, you should include your pevious question and append the additional info below it. regarding your question you just need to add player.volume=1.0 on the pause code block

Comment: Like this?   var player = document.getElementById('player');
  if (player.paused);.volume='1.0'